# Missing jfxwebkit, but installation is fine (on macOS)

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

For a certain component I'm building I need jfxwebkit but I always get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jfxwebkit in java.library.path:
```

I am using openjdk-15. Is there any way for me to manually add jfxwebkit, or any fix like that since its a must for this component?

Comment: do you find a solution yet ?

Answer (score -1):

OpenJDK doesn't typically include JavaFX at all.

If you used a build of OpenJDK from Bellsoft that includes JavaFX, be sure to read the fine print.  I believe Bellsoft doesn't fully support the javafx.web module.  I think Zulu builds from Azul that bundle JavaFX may include the full javafx.web module though.

The other option of course is to follow the instructions on OpenJFX.io to build your application, and create your own JRE image for the application as is that the recommended way to distribute Java applications these days.